# In excel is it possible to dynamically (programmatically) display rows that have a speific column value?

Tags: excel

I have a row of data.  ONe of these fields is updated dynamically.  The field is called overdue date.  When the document is opened, this field adds 2 weeks onto another field value called date requested, thus coming up with a date.

I would like a function that checks whether this overdue date is the same value or less than today's date (ie is it overdue) and if it is, show this row in another section in the spreadsheet.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this that I can think of.  One is advanced level and the other is expert level.

The first is to use a macro, which records a specific set of actions.  So open the file, then record a macro:

Start Recording:go to cell A1, then navigate to the dataset, then sort it, then END Recording.  You could put a button on the page and assign the macro to it.

Then, the user would open the workbook, click the button and that's it.

The second way would be to use VBA, there is an event handler for when a workbook is opened that could run that macro, but this is was complex if you are not already familiar with VBA.